# RequireJS and Backbone View - this not correctly scoped in initialize

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

Getting the following error when initializing a Backbone View:

```
this.collection.on is not a function
```

I have the following View:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'events',
    'utils',
    'text!../../templates/vehicles-template.html'
],
function (
    $,
    _,
    Backbone,
    vent,
    utils,
    vehiclesTemplate) {

    var VehiclesView = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: vehiclesTemplate,
        initialize: function () {
            this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this); //error:  this.collection.on is not a function
            utils.log('Vehicles view initialized');
        },
        render: function() {
            this.$el.empty().html(this.template({ vehicles: this.collection.toJSON() }));
            return this;
        }
    });

    return VehiclesView;
});
```

**this** is returning the view, but does not fails on collection or model when trying to bind to events.

What I am missing here?

Comment: How are you `new`ing up your view? Looks like your `collection` is not a collection.

Comment: How you construct your view? Something like VehiclesView({model: collection})?

Comment: wasn't passing in a collection. @fencliff answer and I will give it to you. cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in question comments, you need to pass the `collection` property to the view:

```
 var view = new VehiclesView({collection:collection});
```